# SAS replicates values

Tags: sas

I have a table with some millions records. There, I have a column looking like that (goes from 1 to 7 for hundreds of times)

[image]

I would like to add an index (say nweeks) looking like that,

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing more of the data table and it's potential natural ordering columns you could create a DATA step view

```
data work.big_with_week / view=work.big_with_week;
  set big;
  if list = 1 then nweek + 1;
run;
```

The syntax *variable*`+`*expression* is known as a `SUM` statement.

> The sum statement is equivalent to using the SUM function and the RETAIN statement, as shown here:
>   
>   `retain variable 0;
>   variable=sum(variable,expression);`

Thus, the retained variable `nweek` is only incremented when the `list` value is `1`.  If your `big` data ever becomes disordered or otherwise **not** uphold the implicit contract of `list` being sequenced 1..7 the view will not be accurate.